# Can Java SWT GridLayout lay out widgets from right to left?

Tags: java, layout, swt

From [API document](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridLayout.html) of GridLayout: "Widgets are laid out in columns from left to right,...", I'm wondering if there is someway to lay out the widgets from right to left? Or, when I just have one column which applies GridLayout, can I lay out widgets from bottom to top? (Sorry for my poor English!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic word here is [`SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#RIGHT_TO_LEFT). However, it is not applied to the `Layout`, but to the `Composite` containing your widgets.

Here is some example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    shell.setText("ExpandBar Example");

    Composite ltr = new Composite(shell, SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    ltr.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    ltr.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    Composite rtl = new Composite(shell, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    rtl.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    rtl.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        new Button(ltr, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button " + i);
        new Button(rtl, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button " + i);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

---

To get both right-to-left and bottom-to-top, you'll just have to use `moveAbove`/`moveBelow` with `null` as the parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    Composite ltr = new Composite(shell, SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    ltr.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    ltr.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    Composite rtl = new Composite(shell, SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    rtl.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    rtl.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    int nrOfItems = 10;
    int nrOfColumns = ((GridLayout) rtl.getLayout()).numColumns;
    int fillerItems = nrOfColumns - nrOfItems % nrOfColumns;

    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfItems; i++)
    {
        new Button(ltr, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button " + i);
        new Button(rtl, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button " + i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < fillerItems; i++)
        new Label(rtl, SWT.NONE);

    Control[] children = rtl.getChildren();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    {
        children[i].moveAbove(null);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, That's great!! I tried and I got the expected result, so now I know how to laid out the buttons from right to left. But I have one more question: Can I laid out the buttons not only from right to left, but also vertically from bottom to top? (the example you gave above is from top to bottom...)

Comment: @Chipunpun Both at the same time or just bottom to top on its own?

Comment: Both! I would be appreciated if you could tell me how! And I found a way to lay out just from bottom to top (single column), that is using the moveAbove() method, is that right?

Comment: @Chipunpun Let me first try to understand. What would the result for 10 buttons in a grid of width 3 look like? Are the first two cells empty? Or should it look like the right part of my image, just with different button labels?

Comment: First two cells empty. Can that happen?

Answer (score 1):

By referring to [SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#gridlayout) , I found a way to lay out widgets from bottom to top vertically(in the case of single column), just use the [moveAbove() method](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FControl.html) of Control(in this case buttons are generated, Button is a subclass of Control).

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    shell.setText("GridLayout Example");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        btn.setText("Button " + i);
        btn.moveAbove(null); 
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

can't post a pic to show the result, for I'm new here, not enough reputation, sorry.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about `moveAbove(null)`, that of course makes it easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how to data you want to add is represented, you could perhaps just reverse your loop when creating the components before adding them to the panel? Assuming that you have an array of data, instead of going `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`, you can just `for (i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)` which will create a "reverse" effect?